# How to change in jquery date picker 'Set Date' into 'Choose date'

Tags: jquery, html, date

I use in a form the jquery date picker. Use for customers who can choose a date to book something. But on mobile phones it shows "Set Date" instead of "Choose date" (I got complaints from customers who thought it would set the date of there phones)

```
  <td><label for="entry_134909635">Datum </label></td>
       <td><input type="date" name="Datum" value="" id="entry_134909635" ></td>
```

How can I change that on smartphones the datepicker ask for Choose date? (or rather the dutch version which should be 'Kies datum'

Comment: Give the full html to see what date picker you using

Comment: Did you try to use the placeholder attribute on your input?